# Use wget to check md5 of online file

Tags: bash, md5, wget

I'm trying to check the MD5 of a file online using this command in the Mac terminal:

```
wget https://player.vimeo.com/external/blahblah.sd.mp4?s=blahblah&profile_id=165 | md5 | awk '{print $1}'
```

But the MD5 hash is returned instantaneously. It isn't actually downloading the file first. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` and `&` are shell metacharacters.

Your code will run

```
wget https://player.vimeo.com/external/blahblah.sd.mp4?s=blahblah &
```

(in the background), then

```
profile_id=165 | md5 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Step 1 is quoting the URL:

```
wget 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/blahblah.sd.mp4?s=blahblah&profile_id=165' | md5 | awk '{print $1}'
```

The next issue is that `wget` doesn't write to stdout, so you'll probably end up with a file called `blahblah.sd.mp4?s=blahblah&profile_id=165` at this point.

This can be changed with [the `-O` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options):

```
wget -O - 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/blahblah.sd.mp4?s=blahblah&profile_id=165' | ...
```

Comment: Thank you. Enormously helpful and quick response.